# Rails : Redirect to previous page with AJAX Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, back-button, browser-history

I have this page where I have a form_remote_tag that returns an AJAX, paginated response :

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => searchs_path, :html => {:id => "search_form"} do %>

<!-- Blah -->

<% end %>
```

Results are printed in another div and point to totally different views. Now my main concern is not about browsing through the paginated results. My objective is that once I click on a result thus going to a different URL, I can just get back to the main search form *filled* with *the previous AJAX response*.

I tried using the HTML5 history API but it looks like it just helps browsing through the one-pager (which is not top-priority for me). I am thinking about page caching though it might be an overkill. Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to solve the problem by storing AJAX DOM Data via [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) API.